# How automatically fill a form with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I have a website that changes his inputs ids, and I'm trying to make a semi auto-login, filling automatically the email and the password part...

I'm doing this with greasemonkey and jQuery...

I'm trying something like this

```
$("input[@type=text]").setValue("email@gmail.com");
```

but had no success... 
The Page has only the login part, two text type inputs...

What am I missing here?

Comment: In the time you needed to write this question you could have easily found out by reading the docs. Being lazy pays only if you actually *save time* by asking somebody else...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery changed it's selectors (to match CSS3 selectors, find all selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)). Try

```
$("input[type=text]").val("email@gmail.com");
```

Comment: and who do I fill the password now? is there a way to first fill an input with a text and then fill another one with other text?

Comment: Well, the password should be `type="password"`. And otherwise, try to use the `name` of the input. `$("input[name=check_what_it_is_called]")...`

Answer (score 3):

There is no `setValue()` method. Use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). Assuming:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email">
```

use:

```
$("#email").val("email@gmail.com"); // ID selector
```

If it doesn't have an ID:

```
$("input[name=email]").val("email@gmail.com");
```

But favour IDs over attribute selectors where possible.

The problem with:

```
$("input[type='text']").val("...");
```

is that it will assign a value to only the first text input on the form. If that's the right one, I guess that's fine. But if you're filling in multiple different inputs you need a different selector.